# While loop gets killed when refreshing div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this JavaScript code refreshing my `watcher.php` file every 5 seconds and that works great. The first page load is fine but after the 5 seconds and so on the `while` loop gets killed. Any reason?

### `index.php` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $('.view').load('watcher.php');
  }, 5000); // refresh div time
</script>

<body>
  <div class="view">
    <?php include 'watcher.php'; ?>
  </div>
</body>
...
```

### `watcher.php` file

```
include 'config.php';

$sql = "SELECT id, name, available, will_return, status  FROM check_in_out";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo '<div style="margin-top:35px;"><center>';

echo '<table class="pure-table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Available</th>
    <th>Status/Comments</th>
    <th>I\'ll Return At:</th>
    <th>Returned</th>
</thead>
</tr>
';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    // output data of each row 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="imgs/card.jpg"> <a class="various" href="#'.$i.'"/>'.$row["name"];'</a></td>';
        echo "<td>"; 
            if ($row['available'] == 1) {
                echo "<img src='imgs/available.gif'/>";
                echo "Online";
            } else {
                echo "<img src='imgs/not-available.gif'/>";
                echo "<span style='vertical-align:middle'>Away</span>";
            };
        echo "</td>";
        echo '<td>'.$row["status"];'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["will_return"];'</td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<div align="center" id="'.$i++.'" style="display:none;width:520px;">
            <h2>'.$row["name"].'</h2>
            <!-- <h4>Current Status: '.$row["status"].'</h4> -->

            <form method="post" action="statusChange.php" />
            <input type="hidden" value="'.$row["id"].'" name="id"/>

            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Comment/Status Here..." name="comment"></textarea>
            <br/><br/>
            When will you return? - <input type="time" name="e_time">
            <br/><br/>
            <input class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type="submit" value="Leave/Return"> 
            </form> 
        </div>';
       }
} else { 
    echo "0 employees";
}

echo '</tr></table>';
echo '</div></center>';

$conn->close();
```

### UPDATE:

What is by this is that look at image below. You will notice that after the first load (5 seconds) the clickable (href) gets killed...

[image]

Comment: what do you mean the while loop kets killed? Are you saying it taks longer than 5 seconds to run the php code?

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, I might of explained that wrong. Here is what I mean. Look at the clickable names. They go away after the first 5 second load.. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/465443/Screen-Shot-2015-11-19-at-1.59.44-PM-1.gif

Comment: This is not a good idea to make things like this... The very first thing I see and don't want to see what is further is that you put asynchronus load() inside interval. There is no warranty that your load() will end until next interval transition fires. First problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var updateWatcher = function() {

   $.ajax({
      url: 'watcher.php',
      success: function(response) {

         $('.view').html(response);

         window.setTimeout(function(){
             updateWatcher();
         }, 3500);
      }
   });

}

updateWatcher();
</script>
```

Granted, this could be solved more elegantly with something like [promises](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20promises), but as far as a simple fix you could try something like this where the timer is only setup once the response has been successfully received. This should be more reliable.

Here is a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/26mahomm/3/ (look in the console).

Comment: Thanks Brian! Please check out my UPDATE! That's the issue i'm facing. Thanks again!

Comment: Brian, I've tried your code. Nothing. After the refresh those names are not clickable anymore. Weird..

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle? As far as your href getting killed, that may have to do w/ the extra slash (/) you have on your anchor tag that gets injected. `<a class="various" href="#'.$i.'"/>'.$row["name"];'</a>`. Notice you are treating the anchor as a self-closing tag, ("/>") but yet you also have a closing anchor ("</a>").

Comment: You're the man! That was it! The extra slash! Wow... I can't believe that. Thank you